# Zenity (or alternative) with custom file selector

Tags: file-manager, alternatives, zenity

When I use zenity and type `--file-selection`, if spawns the default GTK file selector. The problem with that is, of course, the lack of image thumbnails. Considering that I want to make an image selection like that, it is a bit of a downside.

Is there a possibility to force zenity to use something like `nemo` or `nautilus` as its file selector?

Or something like `qarma` (it is a qt based rewrite of zenity). Can also be `yad` etc.

Anyone got any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

try `yad --file --add-preview --large-preview`

in this mode when you select image or any previously thumbnailed file a preview widget appears at the right of the file list

Comment: Cheers. It kinda works, but not ideal, as one can not view many pictures at once etc. Still, better than nothing.

Comment: if you need an image-only selector you can write your own. this is a proof of concept - https://pastebin.com/JjZB3VSB

Answer (score 1):

As a programmer, you open a file selection dialog by calling the appropriate function from your GUI toolkit – in the case of zenity, that'd be GTK's file chooser. So, no: you cannot change that.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Do you know if any similar program (such as yad or qarma) allow for that?

Comment: Since neither nemo nor nautilus are file selector dialogs, I'm afraid I don't

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Have a nice day :)